# Quicksort weird results?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, partitioning, quicksort

I very recently learnt `quicksort`. I read that pivot selection plays a very important role in the overall performance. 
I had an assignment where I was supposed to test 3 variations of pivot selection - **randomized, median of three and median of medians** on varying input sizes. 
I had read that the median of medians version is will not run in O(n2) even in worst case. But in my results, **randomized and median of three versions gave almost similar results, with median of three doing slightly better, but median of medians is performing very poorly by several orders of magnitude**. For instance, on input size of 50000, the randomized version ran in `16547 us` while the median of medians ran in `1139168 us`.
Can somebody explain why is this happening? (As far as I know I have implemented the pivot selection algorithm correctly- diving array into sets of 5, taking median of each set and again doing this recursively till I get the median.)  Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I am rechecking the code just in case, but is it normal for the median of medians implementation to work just as slow or even slower(if only marginally) than the other two implementations or is it guaranteed to work much faster?

Edit2: Here's the code which I use for finding median of medians, the value that it finds is returned to the quicksort function to use as pivot. I am sure that the code  violates all good coding practices, please ascribe this to my noob-ishness and try to look beyond it.

```
int getpivot(int arr[], int low, int high) {

        int i,j,k,l,val,med[MAX/4],temp[6],pivot,mi,index,temp2;
        if(high-low+1<=5) { //returns median if size of array<=5
            for(i=1;i<=high;i++) {
                val=arr[i];
                j=i-1;
                while(j>=0 && val<arr[j]) {
                    arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                    j--;
                }
                arr[j+1]=val;
            }
            return arr[(low+high)/2];   
        }

        mi=0;
        // divide array into groups of 5, 
        //finds median of those groups by insertion sorting
        //adds these medians to med array
        for(i=low;i+5<=high;) {
            index=0;
            for(j=i;j<i+5;j++)
                temp[index++]=arr[j];
            i+=5;
            for(k=1;k<5;k++) {
                val=temp[k];
                l=k-1;
                while(l>=0 && temp[l]>val) {
                    temp[l+1]=temp[l];
                    l--;
                }
                temp[l+1]=val;
            }
            med[mi++]=temp[2];
        }


        //choose random index as pivot and partition the med array
        pivot=rand()%mi;
        i=low=0;
        j=high=mi-1;

        while(i<j) {
            while(i<high && med[i]<=med[pivot]) i++;
            while(med[j]>med[pivot]) j--;
            if(i<j) {
                temp2=med[i];
                med[i]=med[j];
                med[j]=temp2;
            } 
        }
        temp2=med[j];
        med[j]=med[pivot];
        med[pivot]=temp2;

        //j is final position of pivot
        //see if j is left/right or equal to the position of true median of median
        // and recurse accordingly

        low/=5;
        high/=5;
        if(j==(low+high)/2) return med[j];
        else if(j<(low+high)/2) return getpivot(med,j+1,high);
        else return getpivot(med,low,j-1);

    }
```

Comment: I imagine there's a problem with your code...

Comment: If only there were debuggers or profilers...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: i am just a noob man. all i have got is a text editor, compiler and <time.h>.

Comment: People here expect to see your code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your observations are somewhat correct.

**Randomized** and **Median of three** pivot selection should result in good Quicksort performance, while the latter being significantly better, as [recommended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) by R. Sedgewick.

Quicksort can be made `O(nlogn)` in the worst case if the array is divided in equal halves at each step (i.e. median is the pivot). Now, the **Median of Medians** algorithm can find the median in linear time, making Quicksort `O(nlogn)` in the worst case.

*However,* the overhead of Median of Medians is so high that it's almost never used in practice, because it results in much slower performance. So, one cannot judge an algorithm's speed just on the basis of it's time complexity, the constant factors also need to be considered.